# xquery- how to increment a counter variable within a for loop/ how to convert array of string values into node

Tags: xquery

In a java program, I am using Saxon Library to parse some XQuery commands.

Now, first I use tokenize() to split some text into a number of text values.
An example of the text is--

```
Mohan Prakash, Ramesh Saini
```

I use tokenize() on above text with ',' as the delimiter. And store the result of tokenize in variable $var

After this, I want to loop over those text values, and give as output the following--

```
  Mohan Prakash,1
  Ramesh Saini,2
```

As you can see from above, the last value in each row is a counter- for first row, this value is 1, for second row this value=2 and so on...

I thought of using something like the code below--

```
for $t in $var/position()
return concat($var[$t], ',', $t)
```

However I am getting an error that I cannot use position() on $var because $var is expected to be a node.

So there are 2 ways to resolve this--

(a) Convert the values in $var to a node

```
   I tried text{$var} but that is not giving accurate results.
```

How do I convert the array of values into nodes?

(b) Use the following--

```
      for $t in $var
```

Here, how do I create and use a counter within the for loop, so that the count value can be output along with each value of $t?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `at` keyword inside the `for` clause:

```
let $var := tokenize('Mohan Prakash, Ramesh Saini', ', ')
for $t at $pos in $var
return concat($t, ',', $pos)
```

This returns the two strings `Mohan Prakash,1` and `Ramesh Saini,2`.

Answer (score 1):

**This XQuery** (which also happens to be an XPath 2.0 expression):

```
for $text in 'Mohan Prakash, Ramesh Saini',
    $i in 1 to count(tokenize($text, ','))
        return concat(tokenize($text, ',')[$i], ',', $i, '&#xA;')
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
Mohan Prakash,1
Ramesh Saini,2
```